# Functional testing framework for Installers?

Tags: frameworks, installation, functional-testing

I want to know what are some of the functional testing frameworks for installers? What I am typically looking for:

1. Check if all the registry keys are set/unset
2. Check if all the files are present
3. Check if all the symlinks are set. I am looking for a framework that will work on *nix, windows and the mac platform
4. Pluggable with build scripts.

Any ideas/thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to set this up, I think, would be to have a VMware Workstation, with all the OS and their versions installed.  Create SnapShots for all the clean systems that you have, this will allow you to always validate the installation and uninstall process, which often overlooked in the installations tests.

If you are using MSBuild you can create your own target builds that will compile the version of the installer you want, start the corresponding VM for the installer, and install the application before you even walk in the door in the morning.

Look for the [VMware workstation SDK](http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/sdk_pubs.html), [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [Wix](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/).